# Set created from complex List

Tags: java, list, set

So I have a list containing duplicated entities from database with the same "Id" (it's not the real Id but kind of) but a different CreatedDate.

So I would like to have the latest entity from duplicates with the latest CreatedDate.

Example I have a list of created users :

```
RealId|CreatedDate|Id|Name
1|20170101|1|User1
2|20170102|1|User1Modified
3|20170103|2|User2
4|20170104|2|User2Modified
```

From that list what is the best way to obtain :

```
RealId|CreatedDate|Id|Name
2|20170102|1|User1Modified
4|20170104|2|User2Modified
```

This is my first idea

```
List<T> r = query.getResultList();

Set<T> distinct = r.stream().filter(x -> {
    List<T> clones = r.stream()
        .filter(y -> y.getId() == x.getId())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    T max = clones.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(AbstractEntityHistory::getEntryDate))
        .get();

    return max.getNumber() == x.getNumber();
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

An other idea I have is to make it order descending by the date then do distinct().collect() like :

```
Set<T> distinct2 = r.stream().sorted((x,y) -> {
   if(x.getEntryDate().isBefore(y.getEntryDate())) {
        return 1;
    } else if(x.getEntryDate().isAfter(y.getEntryDate())) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Here, T overrides equals which watch for the RealId if they are equal else use reflection to watch every other field.

Comment: Can't we make a sql query change?

Comment: Yes I can change the query! I'm using Hibernate so I guess I could make a query that do not select duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<YourObject> collect = activities
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        YourObject::getId, 
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getCreatedDate))))
              .entrySet()
              .stream()
              .map(e -> e.getValue().get())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is used `Collectors.groupingBy` to create a `Map<Integer, Optional<YourObject>>`, grouped by `id` and most recent `createDate`. The you get the `entrySet` for this map and collect it to a `List`.

Comment: Can you explain your approach? This will be way more helpful than a *code only* answer.

Comment: Using Hibernate and H2 Embedded Database, would it be better to "getAll" then use your method or to make a query that will do the same?

Comment: @baskwo - that's the implementation for when you ``getAll`` the  entities

Comment: @SchiduLuca Yeah I understand that :) But I wonder if it would be better and faster to make it a query. Because H2 Embedded databases are limited by the speed of the hard drive so I wonder if it would be faster by making a query that do the same so it would reads less from the harddrive.

Comment: @SchiduLuca not quire sure the editing is in place... but 1) plz edit the code to make it more readable 2) you *could* static import the methods that are needed - making the code even shorter 3) since you only need `values` you can call `values` on the resulting map, not `entrySet` 4) you are calling `get` directly on a *potentially* missing value, you could first `filter` the missing Optionals. Otherwise one plus

Comment: @Eugene ok, I'll take that into consideration, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without java8 functional stuff:

```
    Map<Long, Item> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Item item: items) {
        Item old = map.get(item.getId());
        if (old == null || old.getDate().before(item.getDate())) {
            map.put(item.getId(), item);
        }
    }

    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>(map.values());
```